# Golang json unmarshall

Tags: json, go

I'm new in Go. I have json like this:

```
{
  "3415": {
    "age": 25,
    "name": "Tommy"
  },
  "3414": {
    "age": 21,
    "name": "Billy"
  }
}
```

I want to unmarshall it to struct:

```
type People struct {
    Id map[string]PeopleDetails
}

type PeopleDetails struct {
    Age int `json:"age"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

But while I run it, I see that struct return nil value.
I did read some tutorials, but most of them have predefined keys, as You see here "id" e.g. 3415 is different for every new json.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you used to try to unmarshal this.

Comment: Also note that your input is a JSON object, so you may unmarhsal that into a map, but not directly into a value of `People`. Since `People.Id` is a map, you may unmarshal into `People.Id`.

Comment: Or use `\`json:",inline"\`` for the `Id` field.

Comment: @Adirio The `encoding/json` package does not support the `,inline` option.

Comment: Oh that must be part of the extended library I use :(

Answer (score 1):

When you have to deal with a "dynamic" json key, the answer is use a map of struct.

You can use the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// Use the struct pointed by @Adirio
type People map[string]PeopleDetails
type PeopleDetails struct {
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

var data string = `{"3415":{"age":25,"name":"Tommy"},"3414":{"age":21,"name":"Billy"}}`

func main() {
    var p People
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &p); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

GoPlayground: https://play.golang.org/p/kVzNV56NcTd

Answer (score 0):

Try with these types instead:

```golang
type People map[string]PeopleDetails

type PeopleDetails struct {
    Age int `json:"age"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```